# Pytorch: How to access CrossEntropyLoss() gradient?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to modify the tensor that stores the CrossEntropyLoss() gradient, that is, P(i)-T(i). Where is it stored and how do I access it?

**code:**

```
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
input.register_hook(lambda x: print(" \n input hook: ",x))
print(input)
target = torch.empty(3, dtype=torch.long).random_(5)
print(target)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
criterion.requires_grad = True
loss0 = criterion(input,target)
loss0.register_hook(lambda x: print(" \n loss0 hook: ",x))
print("before backward loss0.grad :",loss0.grad)
print("loss0 :",loss0)
loss0.backward()
print("after backward loss0.grad :",loss0.grad)
```

**output:**

```
tensor([[-0.6149, -0.8179,  0.6084, -0.2837, -0.5316],
        [ 1.7246,  0.5348,  1.3646, -0.7148, -0.3421],
        [-0.3478, -0.6732, -0.7610, -1.0381, -0.5570]], requires_grad=True)
tensor([4, 1, 0])
before backward loss0.grad : None
loss0 : tensor(1.7500, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)

 loss0 hook:  tensor(1.)

 input hook:  tensor([[ 0.0433,  0.0354,  0.1472,  0.0603, -0.2862],
        [ 0.1504, -0.2876,  0.1050,  0.0131,  0.0190],
        [-0.2432,  0.0651,  0.0597,  0.0452,  0.0732]])
after backward loss0.grad : None
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'CrossEntropyLoss() gradient', you specify the gradient with respect to something else that can be modified and then the gradient gives you how much, for example, the loss changes when you change input.

Comment: Imagine my input tensor is an output of a model. Now I want the cross entropy loss gradient respect to the output(i.e input tensor). which mathematically is equal to output prob vector - target vector

Comment: I am curious, is my answer what you are looking for or is it something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your specification in the comments you want the gradient with respect to the input (output of the model), in your code you look at the gradient of the loss which does not exist. So you could so something like:

```py
import torch
input = torch.tensor([1,0,1,0], dtype=float, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4], dtype=float)
loss = (input - target).abs().mean()
loss.backward()
```

Here `loss.grad` gives you `None`, but `input.grad` returns:

```
tensor([ 0.0000, -0.2500, -0.2500, -0.2500], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Which should be the gradient you are interested in.